# How to run cron job without php artisan schedule:run in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have setup my cron job in laravel 6 and link it with laravel scheduler i want it works automatically when condition meets:
Here is my Activitycron.php in app\console\command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\LogActivity;

//use App\LogActivity;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ActivityCron extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'activity:cron';


    protected $description = 'Delete 30 Days Activity-Log';


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function handle()
    {
        $dlt=LogActivity::where('updated_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(1))->delete();
        if($dlt){
            \App\Helpers\LogActivity::addToLog('Activity-log Deleted');

        }
        $this->info('Activity Cron executed successfully');
    }
}
```

And my Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Console\Commands\ActivityCron;
use App\Helpers\LogActivity;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

    protected $commands = [
        ActivityCron::class,
    ];


    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('activity:cron')
            ->everyMinute();
    }


    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

When i run php artisan schedule:run command in termianal then it works but if i don't run this command, then its not work as it will create issue when it will on server as there we don't run any command.
So,
I want cron job run everyminute without typing php artisan schedule:run